# python: how to get list length in list generator expression?

Tags: python

Maybe like this (just a pseudocode)

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  
a = [d for d in li if self.length<3]  
print a  
[1,2]
```

What is a pythonic way to do that thing?

Comment: length? I think you mean value?

Comment: what is `self`?

Comment: You cannot refer to the list being generated in a list comprehension. Why not just `a = li[:2]`?

Comment: Hi Tan, please clarify: is length value?

Comment: sorry,i mean length, i just want to control the loop inside the expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.count()` to keep track of how many elements you have used:

```
from itertools import count

li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
c = count(1)    # initialize to 1
a = [d for d in li if next(c) < 3]   # everytime you add an element 
print (a)                            # in the comprehension `c` is incremented
```

That keeps track of the elements added to the list, hence the length of the list which gives:

```
[1, 2]
```

as expected with length 2.

**EDITED:** More easier way, with `enumerate`:

```
a = [d for idx, d in enumerate(li) if idx < 2]
```

Comment: Please use the `next()` function rather than call the `__next__` method directly. `next(c)` is both more readable and portable across Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Also, why use `count()` when you can use `enumerate()`? There is a direct correlation between `li` and the count.

Comment: Thank you for that tip, its actually didn't cross my mind, `enumerate` really easy and preferred way.